# Deny RDP access to specific server from a particular user via GPO

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, rdp, user-accounts

I have a security issue.

How can I deny RDP access to a specific server(critical server) for a particular Active Directory user using a Group Policy Object (GPO) ?

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  Where are you encountering an issue?

Answer (score 7):

You can use Group Policy to deny the user the right to log on to the server(s) via RDP as shown in the image.

[image]